# API Connections from external data to Google Sheets: JSON parse error

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-sheets

I'm trying to connect a marketing tool to google sheets to then use that data live.
Info about API connection: https://developer.lemlist.com/#get-team-information

I'm attempting to connect it and get the results with the following script (I will then determine how to use that JSON in my sheets but it's not the issue right now).

```
function callNumbers() {
 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.lemlist.com/api/team/\
  --user:key");

var json = response.getContentText();
var data = JSON.parse(json);
Logger.log(data.title);

  

}
```

As you can see on the link, the JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "tea_aaqam5a3BkY8aje24",
  "name": "PiedPiper",
  "userIds": ["usr_aawMB5Gd5JJCFYvjp"],
  "createdBy": "usr_aawMB5Gd5JJCFYvjp",
  "createdAt": "2018-04-30T12:19:42.829Z",
  "apiKey": "aa13722b45b9c475cc686231b1af6583",
  "billing": {
    "quantity": 1,
    "ok": true,
    "plan": "freetrial"
  },
}
```

When running I get the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
If the JSON is not formatted correctly, does this mean there's no way? Because how can I change it if I'm getting it from an external source.

Furthermore, there's a script to get a .csv file of the data I need. Do you know if it's possible to export that into sheets with a script? Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to your second question, here is a script that will give you data in sheet

Put these parameters in cells B2:I2

```
/_id    /name   /createdBy  /createdAt  /apiKey /billing/quantity   /billing/ok /billing/plan
```

Put this formula where you need `=getDataJSON( url , B2:I2 )`
url is either url or data
and this script in the editor

```
// mike.steelson
let resultat = []; 
function getDataJSON(url,xpath){
  try{
    if (url.match(/http(s)?:\/\/?/g)){var data = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText())}
    else{var data = JSON.parse(url)}
    var json = eval('data')
    if (typeof xpath == 'object'){var liste = xpath.join().split(",")} else {var liste = xpath.split("|")}
    if (json.length){json.forEach(function(elem){getData(elem,liste)})} else {getData(json,liste)}
    return resultat
  }
  catch(e) {
    return ('Pas de résultat - vérifier l\'url et les paramètres !');
  }
}
function getData(elem,liste){
  var prov=[]
  liste.forEach(function(chemin){
    var t=chemin.split('/');
    var obj=elem;
    for (var i=1;i<t.length;i++){obj=obj.item(t[i])}
    if(typeof obj=='object'){prov.push('['+obj+']')}else{prov.push(obj)}
  })
  resultat.push(prov)
}
Object.prototype.item=function(i){return this[i]};
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it but I get an error on the "liste.forEach" function. Error is: ReferenceError: list is not defined

Comment: take a copy https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HrviY7UdFxwQ4JYBfYfb4Ojr4NVLjJ-97jytbkILkxU/copy

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to write these json, there is an extra comma

```
{
  "_id": "tea_aaqam5a3BkY8aje24",
  "name": "PiedPiper",
  "userIds": ["usr_aawMB5Gd5JJCFYvjp"],
  "createdBy": "usr_aawMB5Gd5JJCFYvjp",
  "createdAt": "2018-04-30T12:19:42.829Z",
  "apiKey": "aa13722b45b9c475cc686231b1af6583",
  "billing": {
    "quantity": 1,
    "ok": true,
    "plan": "freetrial"
  }
}
```